# undefined method role for nil in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a novice with rails and I have just set up a blog in my application.

I want my guests to be able to see/view the blog but unable to make any changes. The changes edit/update function is only for the admin.

I currently have cancancan and devise installed and they are working great.

my vblogs/index.html.erb file currently looks like this :

```
  <% @vblogs.each do |vblog| %>

      <h2><%= vblog.title %></h2>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <p><b>Created By:<%= vblog.author %></b></p>
      <br>
      <p><b>Posted On:<%= vblog.posted_on %></b></p>
      <br>
      <p><%= vblog.post %></p>
      <br>

      <br>



      <%= link_to 'View', vblog %>


       <% if @user.role == "admin" %>
      <%= link_to 'Change/Update', edit_vblog_path(vblog) %>  |
     <%= link_to 'Delete', vblog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      <br>
     <%= link_to 'Create A New Blog Post', new_vblog_path %>
```

and my vblogs_controller.rb file looks like this :

```
class VblogsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_vblog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /vblogs
# GET /vblogs.json

def index
@vblogs = Vblog.all
@user = current_user
end

 # GET /vblogs/1
 # GET /vblogs/1.json
 def show
 @user= User.all
 end

# GET /vblogs/new
def new
@vblog = Vblog.new
end

# GET /vblogs/1/edit
def edit
if !current_user.admin?
  redirect_to vblogs_path
  return
 end
 @users =User.all
 end

 # POST /vblogs
 # POST /vblogs.json
 def create
 @vblog = Vblog.new(vblog_params)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @vblog.save
    format.html { redirect_to @vblog, notice: 'Vblog was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @vblog }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @vblog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end

 # PATCH/PUT /vblogs/1
 # PATCH/PUT /vblogs/1.json
 def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @vblog.update(vblog_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @vblog, notice: 'Vblog was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @vblog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end

  # DELETE /vblogs/1
  # DELETE /vblogs/1.json

def destroy
@vblog.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to vblogs_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
 end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_vblog
  @vblog = Vblog.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def vblog_params
  params.require(:vblog).permit(:title, :author, :posted_on, :post)
end
end
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix is to check if user is present before you check the role:

```
<% if ( @user.present? && @user.role == "admin" ) %>
```

If @user is not defined then it will return false and not fail on the second part.

Comment: I am getting the following error: undefined method `present' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry I missed the '?' on present?.  try it now.

Answer (score 5):

The only line that could raise this error is

```
   <% if @user.role == "admin" %>
```

So, `@user` is `nil`. That implies that `current_user` must be `nil`. Find out why `current_user` is not set, or, if it's valid for it not to be set, wrap your access of `@user` in some conditional logic.

Comment: @meager I don't know where to set the information for current_user would that be int he controller itself?